# Linux operators issue

Tags: linux, operators

i'm simply trying to test if a directory exists:
- If true, cd into
- If false, mkdir and cd into

I'm doing this:

```
(test -d foo && cd foo) || (mkdir foo && echo 'print' && cd foo)
```

And also this, getting the same result:

```
test -d foo && cd foo || (mkdir foo && echo 'print' && cd foo)
```

That's what i get

```
[dbadmin@osboxes test]$ ll
total 0
[dbadmin@osboxes test]$ (test -d foo && cd foo) || (mkdir foo && echo 'print' && cd exp)
print
[dbadmin@osboxes test]$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 dbadmin verticadba 4096 May 25 10:57 foo
[dbadmin@osboxes test]$
```

As you can see, it creates the dir "foo", but doesn't cd into, even if the `echo test` works (that's simply a kind of a debug).

Also, if i do only `mkdir foo && cd foo` works fine

```
[dbadmin@osboxes test]$ mkdir foo && cd foo
[dbadmin@osboxes foo]$
```

Can you help me?

Comment: The `(mkdir aaa && cd aaa)` invokes a subshell. And the subshell is finished at the`)`

Comment: Thanks, solved with `(test -d foo && cd foo) || (mkdir foo) && cd foo`

Answer (score 1):

Since the only differences between your two code paths are displaying `print` and making the directory, it would be far easier just to use the "make this directory if it doesn't exist" option of `mkdir`:

```sh
[[ -d foo ]] || echo print
mkdir -p foo
cd foo || echo "Something went wrong...
```

And, if you were only displaying `print` so that you knew which branch was being run (this appears to be the case based on your comments in the question), you could just remove that first statement altogether.